# Route PDF pages to specific printer tray based on content

Tags: pdf, printing, printer

I have a large PDF file that contains hundreds of pages. Every *n* page holds the same specific words and the same image. I will call these the *"special pages"*.

The position of these *special pages* is not predictable. That means my PDF can have for example 5 normal pages, then page 6 is a *special page* then 2 normal pages, then again a *special page*, then 12 normal, then 2 *special pages*, etc., etc.

I would need a way to automate the printing of these PDF files so that all normal pages are printed on my printer's paper tray 1, and all *special pages* onto paper tray 2 (because I need specific paper for normal and a different one for the *special pages*).

Does anyone know if there is a way to print the entire PDF file at once and route the *special pages* to a specific printer tray based on

- a text search for the specific words they contain
- or the fact that there is an image
- or even the number of colors on the page (the *special pages* with the images contain many more colors than the other pages)

I will need to do this on a regular basis (once every month).

I am open to any suggestions. Specific software, Powershell, or other programming languages. Any ideas?

Open-source solutions would be best. Windows, Mac or Linux are all viable options for me.

I have found one solution so far, which is [Ricoh Print&Share](https://www.printandshare.info/) but a single licence with 5 years maintenance is about USD 2500. It would be nice to find a cheaper or open-source solution.

Answer (score 2):

You might check out [QPDF](https://qpdf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) which is an open source tool to manipulate PDF files. With it you can split the file into pages, isolate particular pages, and then recombine those pages before sending the separate files to a specific printer. Or you can isolate pages based on particular properties (for example if they contain images), or by file or page length etc. It can also generate a JSON representation of the file characteristics so that you could build an algorithm to split the file based upon those characteristics using another program.

The tool can run on windows or linux machines.

In response to the comment from @MrUpsidown to my suggestion, I provide here an example shell script that takes an inputfile, and splits it up temporarily only to assess the size in bytes of each page. The split up pages are then used to create page lists of "special pages" that are big, and "regular pages" that are small, and then to create the cups lpr commands to send those pages to a printer. The script could be modified to examine each page for a text string (using e.g. pdftotext), or some other unique attribute. Anyway, one list is sent to tray Upper and the other to tray Lower. Then it cleans up after itself. The script will need tweaking to satisfy your needs, and be hardened for production use, but I think it should outline the basic method I was suggesting.

After installing qpdf on a linux machine (or mac) You run the script by creating a file (lets call it "splitpages"), then make it executable via `chmod 755`, then executing the script by invoking `splitpages filename.pdf`. It will currently just print out the commands that could be activated by replacing the "echo" with "eval" in the script. An example of executing the script like this
`splitpages samplefile.pdf`
where samplefile.pdf has 4 pages (3 normal, and the fourth special) would be for it to print out these strings

```
lpr -o media=Upper -o page-ranges=1,2,3, samplefile.pdf
lpr -o media=Lower -o page-ranges=4, samplefile.pdf
```

Of course other things need to be tweaked to suite your needs

```
#!/bin/bash
# print pages based on page size 
# greater than minimumsize goes to tray1
# else goes to tray2
minimumsize=500000
infile=$1
if [ ! -f "$infile" ]; then
    echo "no input file"
    exit
fi

# location of temporary files used to identify page characteristics
outfile=/tmp/test
rm -f ${outfile}*

# split the file so we can assess lengths
qpdf $infile --split-pages $outfile

pnum=0
bigpage=
smallpage=
for page in ${outfile}*
do
    ((pnum++))
    actualsize=$(wc -c <"$page")
    if [ $actualsize -ge $minimumsize ]; then
    #echo size is over $minimumsize bytes
    bigpage="${bigpage}${pnum},"
    else
    #echo size is under $minimumsize bytes
    smallpage="${smallpage}${pnum},"
    fi
done

# replace the echo command with the eval command to actually execute the strings
lprc1="lpr -o media=Upper -o page-ranges=$bigpage $infile"
echo $lprc1
lprc2="lpr -o media=Lower -o page-ranges=$smallpage $infile"
echo $lprc2
rm -f ${outfile}*
```

Comment: I don't want to split, isolate, recombine or anything like that. I want to route specific pages to a specific printer tray based on page content.

Comment: Thanks for the update. This would print all `$bigpage` first, **then** all `$smallpage` right? Maybe that wasn't clear from my question but my goal is to keep the page sequence, ie. *normal page*, *normal page*, *special page* (from different tray) and so on.

Comment: OK, I think I finally understand. the code can be revised to satisfy your needs a few ways. Method one issues the lpr command within the if clause inside the for loop. One lpr command per page. That would likely make a huge print job queue, although obviously you could manage that by inserting pauses to allow the queue to clear. Does that sound worth it? Those mods are very straightforward. Method 2 would assemble the page numbers for a cluster of consecutive normal pages, then consecutive special pages, and issue two lpr commands for those pages. Then repeat till done.

Comment: Right. I think either method would work. Maybe method 2 would be less resource intensive?

Comment: yes, method two would definitely be more desirable since it will produce substantially fewer jobs submitted the print queue. But the coding would be more complicated. I chose bash to use for the example for convenience but you could use other languages (python?) if you want a more elegant programming environment. Let us know how it shakes out, and then clean up this answer with your favorite solution! I like QPDF, so I occasionally like to promote it for these kinds of purposes :-)

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Acrobat Pro along with the
[AutoSplit Pro plug-in](https://evermap.com/AutoSplit.asp)
($149)
can do it. More information to be found in the article
[Extract Pages from a PDF Document Using a Text Search](https://evermap.com/Tutorial_ASP_ExtractPagesByTextSearch.asp).

[image]

You could also automate this yourself using document-level JavaScript
installed in one of Acrobat’s JavaScript folders and
creating an Action that executes the JavaScript.

For an example, see the article
[Extract PDF Pages Based on Content](http://khkonsulting.com/2014/04/extract-pdf-pages-based-content/).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but as far as I can tell, this would only *extract* pages based on custom criteria and not route the print job as I asked in my question. The issue with this is that I need the *normal pages* and *special pages* to be printed in the order they are in the document (they are somehow linked and I must send to every customer the *normal page* together with the *special page* - just they need to be printed on specific paper). Hope I am being clear.

Comment: You could create a more sophisticated workflow with Acrobat JavaScript. Or the AutoSplit plug-in seems to support workflows, but I don't know it well enough to say that it solves it. I added an AutoSplit article to my answer.